# Ember sort an enumerable array or add an new object to a regular array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, ember.js

I have a todo list.
The main template has an input for entering new todos and an outlet.
The outlet is for the todos.index template which displays each todo. I have made them srtable using jquery sortable. I sort them using a model property.

todos route:

```
 model: function(){
        return this.store.filter("todo", {}, function(todo){
            if(todo.get("user") !== null && parseInt(todo.get("user").get("id")) === user_id)
                return todo;
        });
```

todos index route:

```
model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('todos').sortBy('idx');
}
```

controllers:

```
App.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();    

App.TodosIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

But when I add this .sortBy() method my returning array of objects is no longer live and any new todos i create arent added to the template. (they do get created and are in ember data and in my db, but they just arent being added to the template) - When you do sortBy the live array of ember data gets copied into an immmutable regular array.
 If I leave out the sortBy() my new objects populate my template just fine.

any ideas of how to sort an array but keep it enumerble or how to refresh the template?

sortProperties is not working - I dont know why. My list of todos is populated by the objectController.

***EDIT -***

My problem was my own fault. I thought I had this

```
 App.TodosIndexController= Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

But what I actually had was:

```
 App.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

This left me without an explicit controller to do the sorting for me, so for me the solution was to create a new arrayController:

```
 App.TodosIndexController= Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

and use that to do the sorting. Though it wasnt the solution to my problem, my issue was my own obliviousness, it is the right way to sort items so I am going to mark @Kingpins answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your controller sorted, and iterate over the controller (not the model) in your template.

```
App.TodosIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['idx'],
  sortAscending: true
});
```

return your model to just the modelFor

```
model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('todos');
}
```

Or you could create a computed property on the controller and watch the model for updates, updating the computed property

```
App.TodosIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortedTodos: function(){
    return this.get('model').sortBy('idx');
  }.('model.[]')
});
```

and again, return your model to just the modelFor

```
model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('todos');
}
```

The other way to manually update the template, is to just get the model for `TodosIndexController` and manually use `pushObject` to add the new todos to it.  It's just an array of items.

Comment: Dont have access to code right now, will later and will give a try but for option one - this isnt working. sortProperties isnt sorting. I think looking at it now I wasnt too clear about what i have. I think it might be the way i have model set up. There is a TodosController which is an ArrayController and the TodosIndexController which is an object controller. Route for the arraycontroller gets models and filters by userid etc, and then objectController route is the modelsFor('todos') which is the (parent) arrayController. The models are loading in the index template

Comment: and then this template is inserted into the todos template. But I think because they are already loaded in the index template that the sortProperties in the arrayController has no affect.

Comment: The second option looks promising though and ill give it a try later - ive also had the idea that i should make the call for the models in the Index route and then sortProperties might work in the objectController. Dont know if thats all clear or not but... 
Thanks I appreciate the suggestions

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly lost.  sortProperties only will work on array controllers, and sortBy should only work on a collection/array.  I'm not sure if I understood why you were using an object controller (isn't the data a collection?)

Comment: working off the example todo on emberjs.com. the index route referneces the array route so i have access to all the models and then iterate through the models in the index template. I had thought that maybe just having one route and template might be the way to go but with the way my code is now when i switch to that when i sort my template the models get duplicated.

Comment: this is also functionlity that might be useful later so i figured id try and sort it the way it was. I'll try the computed sort and see if i can get something working with that. Once again thanks for the input

Comment: Yeah so Im using Ember-cli and the naming conventions and the way I went about this confused me. The solution was something obvious. I didnt have a `TodosIndexController`. I thought I did and that it was the Object controller but I didnt, what I had was a `TodosController` and a `TodoController` So once I created that I was able to use `sortProperties`